# What is the UniswapV2Factory address on the Sepolia network

Tags: factory, uniswapv2

Does anyone know what's the factory address of UniswapV2 in sepolia?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Uniswap does not support sepolia for v2, so you won't be able to interact with it via uniswap frontend.

if you want to use Sepolia then you need to deploy uniswap on the Sepolia network and then use it simply.

in case you don't want to deploy your own uniswap then you can simply use this particular address which is deployed on Sepolia Network and it works

https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xC532a74256D3Db42D0Bf7a0400fEFDbad7694008

Answer (score 0):

I found the other contracts that are included in the router and factory here:
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x486941CfA4e4E38e4337f1341700E1941cfF5005#code
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x7E0987E5b3a30e3f2828572Bb659A548460a3003#code

in case wanting to get into them

Answer (score 0):

This is the UniswapV2Factory address on the sepolia network:
I found them here:

- https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xc9f18c25Cfca2975d6eD18Fc63962EBd1083e978#code
- https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x5b8bDFd0e2274d507D7511a6f216c5E9F5cD07A1#code
- UniswapV2Factory: 0xc9f18c25Cfca2975d6eD18Fc63962EBd1083e978
- ShusiswapV2Factory: 0x5b8bDFd0e2274d507D7511a6f216c5E9F5cD07A1

Comment: please provide the source of this information. Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).